# orgmode logbook drawer total time not calculated as expected

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use the logbook drawer in a headline like this:

```
* WIP My Project
  :LOGBOOK:
  CLOCK: [2020-01-15 mer. 10:18]--[2020-01-15 mer. 11:18] =>  1:00
  CLOCK: [2020-01-14 mar. 10:12]--[2020-01-14 mar. 11:12] =>  1:00
  CLOCK: [2019-11-13 mer. 14:20]--[2019-11-13 mer. 14:50] =>  0:30
  :END:
```

When I ask for the total time (pressing C-c C-x C-d) I have 2:00 and not 2:30 as expected. The CLOCK entry of 2019 is excluded. I wonder why...
Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `C-u C-u C-c C-x C-d`.  By default, `org-clock-display` uses the range set in `org-clock-display-default-range`, which defaults to `thisyear`.